# Testing async function with synchronous wrapper in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest, python-asyncio

I am trying to test the behaviour of an asynchronous function in the tests suite. I am using python and pytest, but I can't seem to find a good workaround.

The function is located in module 'some_path':

```py
def synchronous(f: Callable) -> Callable:
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper


@app.command()
@synchronous
async def async_function_to_test(some_args):
    nodes = ["foo", "bar"]
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed([loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_function, some_args) for node in nodes]):
        await coro
    return nodes

def sync_function(some_args)
    # do synchronous tasks for a long time
    return some_variable
```

In the test, I need to mock the 'sync_function', that's already been tested before.

```py
import pytest
import some_path
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_async_function(some_fixtures):
    with unittest.mock.patch("some_path.sync_function") as mock:
        some_path.async_function_to_test(some_args)
        ...
```

But I get a pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>: it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock.

Note that I cannot use the @pytest.mark.asyncio in the test, for the synchronous wrapper already calls asyncio.run. The use of pytest-asyncio would call the running_loop twice and raise an error.

How to solve this? Can I make the patch pickable somehow?

Comment: The only solution I thought of is to edit the wrapper with an optional 'loop=None' parameter, that runs a new event loop only when there's no loop already running. However, it looks a bit 'clumsy' as a solution.  Would you consider taking out the @synchronous wrapper all together?